# can't make a 3x3 grid photos

Tags: html, css

I amm trying to make a grid with 3 columns and 3 lines (3x3) but it just doesn't want to work.

I have already tried to set width, display grid, inline-grid copy code from other websites and nothing works. also don't want to lose the quality of the images but the images are all different sizes, if I make a linear grid the images will look different in sizes?
everything i try it just doenst fit, or bugs idk what to do anymore

[image]

```css
@media screen and (min-device-width:698px) {
  div#showgrid {
    width: 698px;
    margin: auto;
  }
}

div.column {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background: #d2c49b;

}

@media (min-device-width: 698px) {
  .column {
    width: 230px;
    height: 230px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
  }
}

.column {
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<h2>Portfólio</h2>
                <div class="myGallery"><div id="showgrid">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="column"><img src="photos/port/photo-1.jpg"></div>
             <div class="column"><img src="photos/port/photo-1.jpg"></div>
            <div class="column"><img src="photos/port/photo-1.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column"><img src="photos/port/photo-1.jpg"></div>
        <div class="column"><img src="photos/port/photo-1.jpg"></div>
        <div class="column"><img src="photos/port/photo-1.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column"><img src="photos/port/photo-1.jpg"></div>
        <div class="column"><img src="photos/port/photo-1.jpg"></div>
        <div class="column"><img src="photos/port/photo-1.jpg"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did refactored your code, you need just to set your own images.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: serif;
}

h1 {
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.myGallery {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(50px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, minmax(50px, 1fr));
  grid-template-areas: 
  'photo1 photo2 photo3'
  'photo4 photo5 photo6'
  'photo7 photo8 photo9';
  gap: 5px;
}

figure.column {
  position: relative;
}

figure.column:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-area: photo1;
}

figure.column:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-area: photo2;
}

figure.column:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-area: photo3;
}

figure.column:nth-of-type(4) {
  grid-area: photo4;
}

figure.column:nth-of-type(5) {
  grid-area: photo5;
}

figure.column:nth-of-type(6) {
  grid-area: photo6;
}

figure.column:nth-of-type(7) {
  grid-area: photo7;
}

figure.column:nth-of-type(8) {
  grid-area: photo8;
}

figure.column:nth-of-type(9) {
  grid-area: photo9;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>Portfólio</h1>
<div class="myGallery">
  <figure class="column">
    <img src="http://www.downgraf.com/media/2014/12/Conceptual_photography_of_Caras_Ionut-7.jpg" />
    <figcaption>Title</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="column">
    <img src="http://www.downgraf.com/media/2014/12/Conceptual_photography_of_Caras_Ionut-7.jpg" />
    <figcaption>Title</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="column">
    <img src="http://www.downgraf.com/media/2014/12/Conceptual_photography_of_Caras_Ionut-7.jpg" />
    <figcaption>Title</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure class="column">
    <img src="http://www.downgraf.com/media/2014/12/Conceptual_photography_of_Caras_Ionut-7.jpg" />
    <figcaption>Title</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="column">
    <img src="http://www.downgraf.com/media/2014/12/Conceptual_photography_of_Caras_Ionut-7.jpg" />
    <figcaption>Title</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="column">
    <img src="http://www.downgraf.com/media/2014/12/Conceptual_photography_of_Caras_Ionut-7.jpg" />
    <figcaption>Title</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="column">
    <img src="http://www.downgraf.com/media/2014/12/Conceptual_photography_of_Caras_Ionut-7.jpg" />
    <figcaption>Title</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="column">
    <img src="http://www.downgraf.com/media/2014/12/Conceptual_photography_of_Caras_Ionut-7.jpg" />
    <figcaption>Title</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="column">
    <img src="http://www.downgraf.com/media/2014/12/Conceptual_photography_of_Caras_Ionut-7.jpg" />
    <figcaption>Title</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: see i think the problem is in other part of the code and i can't find it.
the images should be in a 3x3 grid but they don't stay where they should be
they are all scrambled